# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'char java.lang.String.charAt(int)' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android

Я хочу реализовать ImageView, который будет менять свой цвет.

> Вот мой код:

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

        View RootView1 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_diary, container, false);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) RootView1.findViewById(R.id.image_fir);
        String[] colorsForDiary;
        colorsForDiary = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.mdcolor_random);
        String color;
        color = colorsForDiary[randInt(0, (colorsForDiary.length - 1))];
        imageView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(color));

        return RootView1;
    }
    public static int randInt(int min, int max) {

        // Usually this can be a field rather than a method variable
        Random rand = new Random();
        // nextInt is normally exclusive of the top value,
        // so add 1 to make it inclusive
        int randomNum = rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;

        return randomNum;
    }
```

> Вот XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/grey_10"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="256dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">


        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlwaysCollapsed"
            app:titleEnabled="false">
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <com.mederov.timelord.TextViewPlus
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/txt1_splash_startorleft"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/txt1_splash_startorleft"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/txt1_splash_margin_toporbottom"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/txt1_splash_margin_toporbottom"

            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Ежедневник"
            android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
            android:textSize="29sp"
            android:typeface="serif"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/lyt_progress"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.969"
            app:customFont="fonts/gothic.ttf">

    </com.mederov.timelord.TextViewPlus>

        <com.mederov.timelord.TextViewPlus
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/txt1_splash_startorleft"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/txt1_splash_startorleft"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/txt1_splash_margin_toporbottom"

            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/txt1_splash_margin_toporbottom"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="“Быть любимым — это больше, чем быть богатым, потому что быть любимым означает быть счастливым.”"
            android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:typeface="serif"
            app:customFont="fonts/gothic.ttf"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/lyt_progress"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.5">

        </com.mederov.timelord.TextViewPlus>
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image_fir"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>



        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/nested_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:scrollingCache="true"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">








    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

> LogCat

```
2019-03-09 15:10:08.724 6422-6422/? E/ACRA: Initializing ANR detector for process: com.facebook.services
2019-03-09 15:10:08.947 1492-1546/? E/ANDR-PERF-JNI: Iop tryGetService failed
2019-03-09 15:10:09.256 841-1086/? E/vendorRil: vendor_ril_send_hook_response: command id is 590829 
2019-03-09 15:10:09.256 841-1086/? E/vendorRil: print respdataSizeDEF = 0
2019-03-09 15:10:10.445 1492-1531/? E/zygote64: Error encountered killing process cgroup uid 99120 pid 5658: No such file or directory
2019-03-09 15:10:10.986 6534-6534/? E/ACRA: Initializing ANR detector for process: com.facebook.katana
2019-03-09 15:10:12.324 1492-1758/? E/AlarmManagerService: set type=3
2019-03-09 15:10:12.333 1492-11488/? E/AlarmManagerService: set type=3
2019-03-09 15:10:12.525 567-608/? E/ANDR-PERF-MPCTL: Invalid profile no. 0, total profiles 0 only
2019-03-09 15:10:12.527 1492-11488/? E/ActivityTrigger: activityStartTrigger: not whiteListedcom.mederov.timelord/com.mederov.timelord.MainActivity/1
2019-03-09 15:10:12.528 1492-11488/? E/ActivityTrigger: activityResumeTrigger: not whiteListedcom.mederov.timelord/com.mederov.timelord.MainActivity/1
2019-03-09 15:10:12.537 1492-4944/? E/ActivityTrigger: activityResumeTrigger: not whiteListedcom.mederov.timelord/com.mederov.timelord.MainActivity/1
2019-03-09 15:10:13.732 841-1086/? E/vendorRil: vendor_ril_send_hook_response: command id is 590829 
2019-03-09 15:10:13.732 841-1086/? E/vendorRil: print respdataSizeDEF = 0
2019-03-09 15:10:13.852 1492-1546/? E/ANDR-PERF-JNI: Iop tryGetService failed
2019-03-09 15:10:14.933 5829-5837/? E/SpellCheckerSession: ignoring processOrEnqueueTask due to unexpected mState=TASK_CLOSE scp.mWhat=TASK_CLOSE
2019-03-09 15:10:15.608 1492-2091/? E/ZteBatteryService: ZTE level= 100  status= 2  mLedBlinkEnabled= true  mLedTimeEnabled= true  mLedBlinkEnabled_batchg= false  mLedBlinkEnabled_batlow= falseMFV FEATURE:false;mLcdOn:trueZTE_HOMEPHONE_ENABLE:false
2019-03-09 15:10:16.184 6534-6615/? E/CompactDiskManagerImpl.cpp: Failed to remove new folder structure directories: No such file or directory
2019-03-09 15:10:16.936 841-1086/? E/vendorRil: vendor_ril_send_hook_response: command id is 590829 
2019-03-09 15:10:16.936 841-1086/? E/vendorRil: print respdataSizeDEF = 0
2019-03-09 15:10:16.951 1945-1945/? E/systemUI_FeatureSignalClusterViewAdapt: Failed to get drawable for 504
2019-03-09 15:10:16.954 1945-1945/? E/systemUI_FeatureSignalClusterViewAdapt: Failed to get drawable for 504
2019-03-09 15:10:17.641 6335-6335/com.mederov.timelord E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.mederov.timelord, PID: 6335
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'char java.lang.String.charAt(int)' on a null object reference
        at android.graphics.Color.parseColor(Color.java:1384)
        at com.mederov.timelord.DiaryFragment.onCreateView(DiaryFragment.java:41)
        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2439)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1460)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1784)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1852)
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:802)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2625)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2411)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2366)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2273)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
2019-03-09 15:10:18.181 1492-1529/? E/ActivityTrigger: activityResumeTrigger: not whiteListedcom.stackexchange.marvin/com.stackexchange.marvin.ui.BaseActivity/190
2019-03-09 15:10:18.182 567-608/? E/ANDR-PERF-MPCTL: Invalid profile no. 0, total profiles 0 only
2019-03-09 15:10:18.243 443-443/? E/hw-IPCThreadState: attemptIncStrongHandle(101): Not supported
2019-03-09 15:10:18.243 443-443/? E/hw-IPCThreadState: attemptIncStrongHandle(101): Not supported
2019-03-09 15:10:19.476 6628-6682/? E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.vk.im.providers.im
2019-03-09 15:10:19.496 841-1086/? E/vendorRil: vendor_ril_send_hook_response: command id is 590829 
2019-03-09 15:10:19.496 841-1086/? E/vendorRil: print respdataSizeDEF = 0
2019-03-09 15:10:19.507 1945-1945/? E/systemUI_FeatureSignalClusterViewAdapt: Failed to get drawable for 505
2019-03-09 15:10:19.509 1945-1945/? E/systemUI_FeatureSignalClusterViewAdapt: Failed to get drawable for 505
2019-03-09 15:10:21.908 6534-6614/? E/fb4a.BootIdReader: Error reading boot_id from procfs
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: /proc/sys/kernel/random/boot_id (Permission denied)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:200)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:150)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:103)
        at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:58)
        at X.2lD.D(:431041)
        at X.Mhg.<init>(:2582344)
        at X.Mhg.B(:2582336)
        at X.OaY.B(:2449057)
        at X.0P7.B(Unknown Source:80)
        at X.0PS.H(:42601)
        at X.0PS.F(:42615)
        at X.4Ef.B(:632756)
        at X.4DL.init(:629542)
        at X.3On.runNextINeedInit(:523719)
        at X.40W.run(:602876)
        at X.0We.run(:137473)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:457)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:457)
        at X.0XQ.run(:48958)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:457)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at X.1lK.run(:252938)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
        at X.1lN.run(:252958)
        at X.0XR.run(:48963)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
2019-03-09 15:10:22.811 1492-4944/? E/AlarmManagerService: set type=2
2019-03-09 15:10:22.813 1492-4944/? E/AlarmManagerService: set type=2
2019-03-09 15:10:23.018 6962-6962/? E/ACRA: Initializing ANR detector for process: com.facebook.services
2019-03-09 15:10:24.078 2766-24911/? E/JavaBinder: *** Uncaught remote exception!  (Exceptions are not yet supported across processes.)
    java.lang.RuntimeException: android.os.RemoteException: NFC is not enabled
        at android.os.Parcel.writeException(Parcel.java:1882)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:710)
     Caused by: android.os.RemoteException: NFC is not enabled
        at com.android.nfc.NfcService$NxpNfcAdapterExtrasService.getSelectedUicc(NfcService.java:4228)
        at com.nxp.nfc.INxpNfcAdapterExtras$Stub.onTransact(INxpNfcAdapterExtras.java:142)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:697)
2019-03-09 15:10:24.130 2296-2296/? E/PhoneInterfaceManager: [PhoneIntfMgr] iccOpenLogicalChannel: Exception: com.android.internal.telephony.CommandException: NO_SUCH_ELEMENT
2019-03-09 15:10:24.132 7008-7027/? E/SmartcardService - SIM1: internalOpenLogicalChannel(aid): throw NoSuchElementException
2019-03-09 15:10:24.157 2296-2296/? E/PhoneInterfaceManager: [PhoneIntfMgr] iccOpenLogicalChannel: Exception: com.android.internal.telephony.CommandException: NO_SUCH_ELEMENT
2019-03-09 15:10:24.157 7008-7027/? E/SmartcardService - SIM1: internalOpenLogicalChannel(aid): throw NoSuchElementException
2019-03-09 15:10:24.157 7008-7027/? E/SmartcardService ACE ARF: Error opening logical channel applet not found
2019-03-09 15:10:24.181 2296-2296/? E/PhoneInterfaceManager: [PhoneIntfMgr] iccOpenLogicalChannel: Exception: com.android.internal.telephony.CommandException: NO_SUCH_ELEMENT
2019-03-09 15:10:24.181 7008-7027/? E/SmartcardService - SIM1: internalOpenLogicalChannel(aid): throw NoSuchElementException
2019-03-09 15:10:24.181 7008-7027/? E/SmartcardService ACE ARF: Error opening logical channel applet not found
2019-03-09 15:10:24.298 841-1086/? E/vendorRil: vendor_ril_send_hook_response: command id is 590829 
2019-03-09 15:10:24.298 841-1086/? E/vendorRil: print respdataSizeDEF = 0
2019-03-09 15:10:24.322 1945-1945/? E/systemUI_FeatureSignalClusterViewAdapt: Failed to get drawable for 504
2019-03-09 15:10:24.325 1945-1945/? E/systemUI_FeatureSignalClusterViewAdapt: Failed to get drawable for 504
2019-03-09 15:10:24.367 7008-7027/? E/SmartcardService ACE ARF: SIM1 rules not correctly initialized! [Parser] Cannot retreive type
2019-03-09 15:10:24.379 7008-7027/? E/SmartcardService: [Parser] Cannot retreive type
2019-03-09 15:10:30.654 1492-2487/? E/ZteBatteryService: ZTE level= 100  status= 2  mLedBlinkEnabled= true  mLedTimeEnabled= true  mLedBlinkEnabled_batchg= false  mLedBlinkEnabled_batlow= falseMFV FEATURE:false;mLcdOn:trueZTE_HOMEPHONE_ENABLE:false
2019-03-09 15:10:32.332 1492-1758/? E/AlarmManagerService: set type=3
2019-03-09 15:10:33.054 2766-2766/? E/RegisteredServicesCache: Next Tag=services
2019-03-09 15:10:33.055 2766-2766/? E/RegisteredServicesCache: 1invalidateCache:WriteServiceStateToFile
2019-03-09 15:10:33.055 2766-2766/? E/RegisteredServicesCache:  Writing service state Data Always
2019-03-09 15:10:34.222 841-1086/? E/vendorRil: vendor_ril_send_hook_response: command id is 590829 
2019-03-09 15:10:34.222 841-1086/? E/vendorRil: print respdataSizeDEF = 0
2019-03-09 15:10:34.247 1945-1945/? E/systemUI_FeatureSignalClusterViewAdapt: Failed to get drawable for 505
2019-03-09 15:10:34.251 1945-1945/? E/systemUI_FeatureSignalClusterViewAdapt: Failed to get drawable for 505
2019-03-09 15:10:36.782 841-1086/? E/vendorRil: vendor_ril_send_hook_response: command id is 590829 
2019-03-09 15:10:36.782 841-1086/? E/vendorRil: print respdataSizeDEF = 0
2019-03-09 15:10:36.806 1945-1945/? E/systemUI_FeatureSignalClusterViewAdapt: Failed to get drawable for 504
2019-03-09 15:10:36.808 1945-1945/? E/systemUI_FeatureSignalClusterViewAdapt: Failed to get drawable for 504
2019-03-09 15:10:37.595 1492-1758/? E/AlarmManagerService: set type=3
2019-03-09 15:10:39.335 841-1086/? E/vendorRil: vendor_ril_send_hook_response: command id is 590829 
2019-03-09 15:10:39.336 841-1086/? E/vendorRil: print respdataSizeDEF = 0
2019-03-09 15:10:44.455 841-1086/? E/vendorRil: vendor_ril_send_hook_response: command id is 590829 
2019-03-09 15:10:44.456 841-1086/? E/vendorRil: print respdataSizeDEF = 0
2019-03-09 15:10:45.085 7045-7069/? E/FA: AppMeasurementReceiver not registered/enabled
2019-03-09 15:10:45.101 7045-7069/? E/FA: Uploading is not possible. App measurement disabled
2019-03-09 15:10:45.724 1492-19730/? E/ZteBatteryService: ZTE level= 100  status= 5  mLedBlinkEnabled= true  mLedTimeEnabled= true  mLedBlinkEnabled_batchg= false  mLedBlinkEnabled_batlow= falseMFV FEATURE:false;mLcdOn:trueZTE_HOMEPHONE_ENABLE:false
2019-03-09 15:10:47.016 841-1086/? E/vendorRil: vendor_ril_send_hook_response: command id is 590829 
2019-03-09 15:10:47.017 841-1086/? E/vendorRil: print respdataSizeDEF = 0
2019-03-09 15:10:52.137 841-1086/? E/vendorRil: vendor_ril_send_hook_response: command id is 590829 
2019-03-09 15:10:52.137 841-1086/? E/vendorRil: print respdataSizeDEF = 0
2019-03-09 15:10:52.171 1945-1945/? E/systemUI_FeatureSignalClusterViewAdapt: Failed to get drawable for 505
2019-03-09 15:10:52.178 1945-1945/? E/systemUI_FeatureSignalClusterViewAdapt: Failed to get drawable for 505
2019-03-09 15:10:52.341 1492-1758/? E/AlarmManagerService: set type=3
2019-03-09 15:10:54.697 841-1086/? E/vendorRil: vendor_ril_send_hook_response: command id is 590829 
2019-03-09 15:10:54.697 841-1086/? E/vendorRil: print respdataSizeDEF = 0
2019-03-09 15:11:00.000 1492-1758/? E/AlarmManagerService: set type=3
2019-03-09 15:11:00.124 1492-1781/? E/AlarmManagerService: set type=2
2019-03-09 15:11:00.127 1492-2487/? E/AlarmManagerService: set type=3
2019-03-09 15:11:00.140 1492-2487/? E/AlarmManagerService: set type=2
2019-03-09 15:11:00.140 1492-2487/? E/AlarmManagerService: set type=3
2019-03-09 15:11:00.566 842-2257/? E/IzatSvc_PassiveLocListener: Exiting with error onLocationChanged line 152 "1"
2019-03-09 15:11:00.646 1492-1781/? E/AlarmManagerService: set type=2
2019-03-09 15:11:02.376 841-1086/? E/vendorRil: vendor_ril_send_hook_response: command id is 590829 
2019-03-09 15:11:02.376 841-1086/? E/vendorRil: print respdataSizeDEF = 0
2019-03-09 15:11:02.396 1945-1945/? E/systemUI_FeatureSignalClusterViewAdapt: Failed to get drawable for 504
2019-03-09 15:11:02.400 1945-1945/? E/systemUI_FeatureSignalClusterViewAdapt: Failed to get drawable for 504
2019-03-09 15:11:03.656 841-1086/? E/vendorRil: vendor_ril_send_hook_response: command id is 590829 
2019-03-09 15:11:03.656 841-1086/? E/vendorRil: print respdataSizeDEF = 0
2019-03-09 15:11:03.683 1945-1945/? E/systemUI_FeatureSignalClusterViewAdapt: Failed to get drawable for 505
2019-03-09 15:11:03.688 1945-1945/? E/systemUI_FeatureSignalClusterViewAdapt: Failed to get drawable for 505
2019-03-09 15:11:07.491 841-1086/? E/vendorRil: vendor_ril_send_hook_response: command id is 590829 
2019-03-09 15:11:07.491 841-1086/? E/vendorRil: print respdataSizeDEF = 0
2019-03-09 15:11:12.362 1492-14209/? E/AlarmManagerService: set type=3
2019-03-09 15:11:12.622 841-1086/? E/vendorRil: vendor_ril_send_hook_response: command id is 590829 
2019-03-09 15:11:12.622 841-1086/? E/vendorRil: print respdataSizeDEF = 0
2019-03-09 15:11:15.177 841-1086/? E/vendorRil: vendor_ril_send_hook_response: command id is 590829 
2019-03-09 15:11:15.177 841-1086/? E/vendorRil: print respdataSizeDEF = 0
2019-03-09 15:11:15.206 1945-1945/? E/systemUI_FeatureSignalClusterViewAdapt: Failed to get drawable for 504
2019-03-09 15:11:15.213 1945-1945/? E/systemUI_FeatureSignalClusterViewAdapt: Failed to get drawable for 504
2019-03-09 15:11:15.512 567-608/? E/ANDR-PERF-MPCTL: Invalid profile no. 0, total profiles 0 only
2019-03-09 15:11:15.664 1492-2487/? E/ZteBatteryService: ZTE level= 100  status= 5  mLedBlinkEnabled= true  mLedTimeEnabled= true  mLedBlinkEnabled_batchg= false  mLedBlinkEnabled_batlow= falseMFV FEATURE:false;mLcdOn:trueZTE_HOMEPHONE_ENABLE:false
2019-03-09 15:11:16.799 567-608/? E/ANDR-PERF-MPCTL: Invalid profile no. 0, total profiles 0 only
2019-03-09 15:11:19.016 841-1086/? E/vendorRil: vendor_ril_send_hook_response: command id is 590829 
2019-03-09 15:11:19.016 841-1086/? E/vendorRil: print respdataSizeDEF = 0
2019-03-09 15:11:19.030 1945-1945/? E/systemUI_FeatureSignalClusterViewAdapt: Failed to get drawable for 505
2019-03-09 15:11:19.033 1945-1945/? E/systemUI_FeatureSignalClusterViewAdapt: Failed to get drawable for 505
2019-03-09 15:11:20.790 567-608/? E/ANDR-PERF-MPCTL: Invalid profile no. 0, total profiles 0 only
2019-03-09 15:11:22.856 841-1086/? E/vendorRil: vendor_ril_send_hook_response: command id is 590829 
2019-03-09 15:11:22.856 841-1086/? E/vendorRil: print respdataSizeDEF = 0
2019-03-09 15:11:25.412 841-1086/? E/vendorRil: vendor_ril_send_hook_response: command id is 590829 
2019-03-09 15:11:25.412 841-1086/? E/vendorRil: print respdataSizeDEF = 0
2019-03-09 15:11:27.977 841-1086/? E/vendorRil: vendor_ril_send_hook_response: command id is 590829 
2019-03-09 15:11:27.977 841-1086/? E/vendorRil: print respdataSizeDEF = 0
2019-03-09 15:11:34.252 1492-19730/? E/ZteBatteryService: ZTE level= 100  status= 5  mLedBlinkEnabled= true  mLedTimeEnabled= true  mLedBlinkEnabled_batchg= false  mLedBlinkEnabled_batlow= falseMFV FEATURE:false;mLcdOn:trueZTE_HOMEPHONE_ENABLE:false
2019-03-09 15:11:35.657 841-1086/? E/vendorRil: vendor_ril_send_hook_response: command id is 590829 
2019-03-09 15:11:35.657 841-1086/? E/vendorRil: print respdataSizeDEF = 0
2019-03-09 15:11:35.692 1945-1945/? E/systemUI_FeatureSignalClusterViewAdapt: Failed to get drawable for 504
2019-03-09 15:11:35.699 1945-1945/? E/systemUI_FeatureSignalClusterViewAdapt: Failed to get drawable for 504
2019-03-09 15:11:37.771 1492-1758/? E/AlarmManagerService: set type=2
2019-03-09 15:11:37.772 1492-1758/? E/AlarmManagerService: set type=3
2019-03-09 15:11:37.790 1492-1781/? E/AlarmManagerService: set type=2
2019-03-09 15:11:38.323 1492-1781/? E/AlarmManagerService: set type=2
2019-03-09 15:11:40.776 841-1086/? E/vendorRil: vendor_ril_send_hook_response: command id is 590829 
2019-03-09 15:11:40.776 841-1086/? E/vendorRil: print respdataSizeDEF = 0
2019-03-09 15:11:40.803 1945-1945/? E/systemUI_FeatureSignalClusterViewAdapt: Failed to get drawable for 505
2019-03-09 15:11:40.808 1945-1945/? E/systemUI_FeatureSignalClusterViewAdapt: Failed to get drawable for 505
2019-03-09 15:11:43.332 841-1086/? E/vendorRil: vendor_ril_send_hook_response: command id is 590829 
2019-03-09 15:11:43.332 841-1086/? E/vendorRil: print respdataSizeDEF = 0
2019-03-09 15:11:45.896 841-1086/? E/vendorRil: vendor_ril_send_hook_response: command id is 590829 
2019-03-09 15:11:45.896 841-1086/? E/vendorRil: print respdataSizeDEF = 0
2019-03-09 15:11:48.445 841-1086/? E/vendorRil: vendor_ril_send_hook_response: command id is 590829 
2019-03-09 15:11:48.445 841-1086/? E/vendorRil: print respdataSizeDEF = 0
2019-03-09 15:11:49.249 1492-19730/? E/ZteBatteryService: ZTE level= 100  status= 5  mLedBlinkEnabled= true  mLedTimeEnabled= true  mLedBlinkEnabled_batchg= false  mLedBlinkEnabled_batlow= falseMFV FEATURE:false;mLcdOn:trueZTE_HOMEPHONE_ENABLE:false
2019-03-09 15:11:52.369 1492-1758/? E/AlarmManagerService: set type=3
2019-03-09 15:11:53.566 841-1086/? E/vendorRil: vendor_ril_send_hook_response: command id is 590829 
2019-03-09 15:11:53.566 841-1086/? E/vendorRil: print respdataSizeDEF = 0
2019-03-09 15:11:54.846 841-1086/? E/vendorRil: vendor_ril_send_hook_response: command id is 590829 
2019-03-09 15:11:54.846 841-1086/? E/vendorRil: print respdataSizeDEF = 0
2019-03-09 15:11:58.692 841-1086/? E/vendorRil: vendor_ril_send_hook_response: command id is 590829 
2019-03-09 15:11:58.692 841-1086/? E/vendorRil: print respdataSizeDEF = 0
2019-03-09 15:12:00.001 1492-1758/? E/AlarmManagerService: set type=3
2019-03-09 15:12:00.064 1492-1781/? E/AlarmManagerService: set type=2
2019-03-09 15:12:00.065 1492-9202/? E/AlarmManagerService: set type=3
2019-03-09 15:12:00.085 1492-14209/? E/AlarmManagerService: set type=3
2019-03-09 15:12:00.567 842-2257/? E/IzatSvc_PassiveLocListener: Exiting with error onLocationChanged line 152 "1"
2019-03-09 15:12:00.588 1492-1781/? E/AlarmManagerService: set type=2
2019-03-09 15:12:03.816 841-1086/? E/vendorRil: vendor_ril_send_hook_response: command id is 590829 
2019-03-09 15:12:03.817 841-1086/? E/vendorRil: print respdataSizeDEF = 0
2019-03-09 15:12:04.251 1492-19730/? E/ZteBatteryService: ZTE level= 100  status= 5  mLedBlinkEnabled= true  mLedTimeEnabled= true  mLedBlinkEnabled_batchg= false  mLedBlinkEnabled_batlow= falseMFV FEATURE:false;mLcdOn:trueZTE_HOMEPHONE_ENABLE:false
2019-03-09 15:12:12.387 1492-9202/? E/AlarmManagerService: set type=3
2019-03-09 15:12:16.623 841-1086/? E/vendorRil: vendor_ril_send_hook_response: command id is 590829 
2019-03-09 15:12:16.623 841-1086/? E/vendorRil: print respdataSizeDEF = 0
2019-03-09 15:12:19.250 1492-9202/? E/ZteBatteryService: ZTE level= 100  status= 5  mLedBlinkEnabled= true  mLedTimeEnabled= true  mLedBlinkEnabled_batchg= false  mLedBlinkEnabled_batlow= falseMFV FEATURE:false;mLcdOn:trueZTE_HOMEPHONE_ENABLE:false
2019-03-09 15:12:21.737 841-1086/? E/vendorRil: vendor_ril_send_hook_response: command id is 590829 
2019-03-09 15:12:21.737 841-1086/? E/vendorRil: print respdataSizeDEF = 0
2019-03-09 15:12:24.297 841-1086/? E/vendorRil: vendor_ril_send_hook_response: command id is 590829 
2019-03-09 15:12:24.297 841-1086/? E/vendorRil: print respdataSizeDEF = 0
2019-03-09 15:12:29.416 841-1086/? E/vendorRil: vendor_ril_send_hook_response: command id is 590829 
2019-03-09 15:12:29.416 841-1086/? E/vendorRil: print respdataSizeDEF = 0
2019-03-09 15:12:31.977 841-1086/? E/vendorRil: vendor_ril_send_hook_response: command id is 590829 
2019-03-09 15:12:31.977 841-1086/? E/vendorRil: print respdataSizeDEF = 0
2019-03-09 15:12:34.536 841-1086/? E/vendorRil: vendor_ril_send_hook_response: command id is 590829 
2019-03-09 15:12:34.536 841-1086/? E/vendorRil: print respdataSizeDEF = 0
2019-03-09 15:12:37.098 841-1086/? E/vendorRil: vendor_ril_send_hook_response: command id is 590829 
2019-03-09 15:12:37.099 841-1086/? E/vendorRil: print respdataSizeDEF = 0
2019-03-09 15:12:37.922 1492-1758/? E/AlarmManagerService: set type=2
2019-03-09 15:12:37.922 1492-1758/? E/AlarmManagerService: set type=3
2019-03-09 15:12:39.662 841-1086/? E/vendorRil: vendor_ril_send_hook_response: command id is 590829 
2019-03-09 15:12:39.662 841-1086/? E/vendorRil: print respdataSizeDEF = 0
```

Comment: Ошибка не в этом коде. Покажите весь стектрейс.

Comment: после падения приложения, перейдите в вкладку Logcat и там будет куча красного текста, от вас просят этот красный текст показать здесь чтобы вам смогли помочь :)